# how to apply same style to windows from in vb.net at design time?

Tags: vb.net

I have a created windows application in VB.net. now I want apply style to it. Like I want apply background color, button style, font type etc from signal setting. And didn't want go and style style to Individual controls.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have already tried?

Comment: Then you might wanna look for custom-themes or something.

Answer (score 3):

There are several solutions:

1. You can store all form settings (the settings that should change for each theme) in `My.Settings` and then apply these settings to each form. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72654-using-settings/) that might help you.

   Example (in the `Load` event handler):

   ```
   ' ...
   Me.BackColor = My.Settings.ThemeBackColor
   ' ...
   ```

   If you have multiple themes that the user can choose from, then store them in separate settings files and read them into the program.

   In order to apply settings to multiple controls, loop through all of them and apply the settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674181/2671135 for more information on how to get all controls of a certain type.
2. You could also create a `Module` with a `Public Sub` similar to this:

   ```
   Public Module Theme
       Public Sub ApplyTheme(ByRef form As System.Windows.Forms.Form)
           With form
               .BackColor = Color.Black
               .Color = Color.Green
               ' ...
           End With
       End Sub
   End Module
   ```

   Inside each form's `Load` event handler, simply call this method:

   ```
   ApplyTheme(Me)
   ```

   Again, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674181/2671135 for more information on how to loop through form controls.
3. Another option would be to create a class that `Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form`. In the constructor method, set all settings as appropriate. Then, for each form, inherit from this class.

I faced the same problem a while ago and I created a DLL that automates the **second solution**. Check it out [on GitHub](https://github.com/georgw777/Main), especially the `ConfigureWindow` method in [this file](https://github.com/georgw777/Main/blob/master/Main/App.cs). It is written in C#.NET though, but I hope it helps anyway...