# reference textboxes as array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Im trying to find a beginner friendly yet effective way to refrences textboxes in a vb form as an array and then loop over them checking for different conditions. Instead of having to go

```
If IsNumeric(firstNameTxt.Text) Then
            MessageBox("First name can only contain letters")
        End If
if IsNumeric(lastNameTxt.Text)
:
:
```

Im trying to do form validation and want to loop over all textboxes in my form  checking that they only contain letter

Comment: could you please explain little more, what you actually looking for?

Comment: `Dim textBoxes As TextBox() = { firstNameTxt, lastNameTxt, ... }` But why? It's more readable to use an `If Else`, all the more because you have different validation texts.

Comment: @Tim thanks! Can I then reference TextBox array as such: if isNumeric(Textbox(x))  ?

Comment: You can loop over all textboxes in the form using @TimSchmelter 's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673950/loop-over-all-textboxes-in-a-form-including-those-inside-a-groupbox

Comment: @Marilee: yes, with LINQ you can even check if all textboxes are numeric: `Dim allNumeric=textBoxes.All(Function(txt) IsNumeric(txt.Text))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do form validation all `textboxes` in the form checking that they only contain letter, you can use the following code:

```
 Dim ctrl As Control
 For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
     If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox And IsNumeric(ctrl.Text) Then
         MsgBox(ctrl.Name.ToString & "  First name can only contain letters")
     End If
 Next
```

Comment: thanks but im getting error in the line MsgBox(ctrl & "Will alows only letter")

Comment: Note that this doesn't search through child controls in panels etc.

Comment: @MattWilko I "love" this messsage: `lastNameTxt First name can only contain letters` ...lastname, firstaname,.. what?

Answer (score 0):

You could just prevent them from even inputting a number which will prevent having to validate it in the first place. I have done this many times with numbers and dates but it should be as simple as this for what you want:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    NonNumericTextboxKeyPress(sender, e)
End Sub
Public Sub NonNumericTextboxKeyPress(ByVal txt As TextBox, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs, Optional ByVal AllowNegative As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal AllowDecimal As Boolean = True)
    If "1234567890".Contains(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```