# Visual Basic, how select all textbox on form?

Tags: forms, visual-studio, textbox

Form has some textbox, i need to check for empty fields. How select all textbox on the form?

May be create variable: Dim TBox AS TextBox

Comment: Are you sure that this is VBA related? Including visual-studio between your tags let me think about VB.NET and WinForms.  Please clarify

Comment: Sorry! I made form in Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If (TextBox1.Text = "") then
Msgbox "TextBox value is empty"
End If
```

Comment: What shoud i do if in the form 100 textboxs?

Comment: You can collect all text boxes controls and iterate through all the text boxes. Can try searching for it in Google, I'm texting from Mobile so can't give you the code

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673950/loop-over-all-textboxes-in-a-form-including-those-inside-a-groupbox