# Loop over every X control into a form even if it is nested

Tags: vb.net

On a **VB.NET** project with **Metroframework Modern UI 1.4.0.0** installed, I use this part of code into a **Module** to loop over all `MetroTextBox`es which placed into a `MetroTabControl` and give `Cursor.Hand` to their **embedded Clear button**. How can I do the same thing including `MetroTextBox`es which could be out of `MetroTabControl`, into my form or into an other container for example? In other words, I would like to loop over every `MetroTextBox` into a form, even if it is nested.

```
Public Sub TxtBoxes_Cursors(sender, e)
    Dim _FormSender = DirectCast(sender, MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm)
    For Each _MetroTabControl As Control In _FormSender.Controls.OfType(Of MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTabControl)()
        For Each _TabPage As Control In _MetroTabControl.Controls.OfType(Of MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTabPage)()
            For Each _Textbox As Control In _TabPage.Controls.OfType(Of MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox)()
                If _Textbox.HasChildren Then
                    For Each _ClearButton As Control In _Textbox.Controls
                        If _ClearButton.Name = "lnkClear" Then
                            _ClearButton.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The word is 'Nested' :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loop over all textboxes in a form, including those inside a groupbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673950/loop-over-all-textboxes-in-a-form-including-those-inside-a-groupbox)

Comment: @AFriend: Thank you very much for your help my friend!!! :)

Comment: Programming language and related technology is indicated by the question's tags. Please do not put them in the title unless they fulfill a specific purpose. Refer to: [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190)

Comment: @Visual Vincent: Sorry!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact answer to my question according to the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673950/loop-over-all-textboxes-in-a-form-including-those-inside-a-groupbox) relevant question which user [A Friend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6144259/a-friend) pointed on comments. First I have to place this `Function` into my `Module`:

```
Public Function FindControlRecursive(ByVal list As List(Of Control), ByVal parent As Control, ByVal ctrlType As System.Type) As List(Of Control)
    If parent Is Nothing Then Return list
    If parent.GetType Is ctrlType Then
        list.Add(parent)
    End If
    For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
        FindControlRecursive(list, child, ctrlType)
    Next
    Return list
End Function
```

And then edit my `Public Sub` like this:

```
Public Sub TxtBoxes_Cursors(sender, e)
    Dim _FormSender = DirectCast(sender, MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm)
    Dim _MetroTextBoxes As New List(Of Control)
    For Each _Textbox As MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox In FindControlRecursive(_MetroTextBoxes, _FormSender, GetType(MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox))
        If _Textbox.HasChildren Then
            For Each _ClearButton As Control In _Textbox.Controls
                If _ClearButton.Name = "lnkClear" Then
                    _ClearButton.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```