# break up html ID into a string as in getElementByID asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

Is there any way in which you can access the properties of an html element by breaking up the id into a string in ASP.NET? By this I am referring to the way in which you can do this with JavaScript to cycle through a numbered set of IDs like an array.

For example I can treat Div1 to Div10 like an array by going:

```
document.getElementByID("Div" + i).innerhtml
```

I cannot seem to find any information on this or a way of asking it in a google search.

If this type of thing is not possible then I would be interested to hear some examples of how else this could be done. I am surprised I cannot find an answer because I am sure many people use the type of method I mentioned in JavaScript.

UPDATE: Please give me a while to give an example of code. I thought this was self explanatory but seemingly it is not... This is VB by the way.

Someone put javascript as a tag!! This is asp.net VB.

Is this basic example enough?

```
sub exampleProcedure()
    For i = 1 to 10
        document.getelementbyid("Div" & i).innerHTML = "A String"
        if i = 5 then
            document.getelementbyid("Div" & i).innerHTML = "This is Div5"
        end if
    next
end sub
```

Oh and it might be worth mentioning that that would work in VbScript (which I have been unfortunate enough to have had to work with at university!)

Comment: Can you show us your ASP.NET code?

Comment: Could you explain a little clearer what you are trying to do with the .NET code?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) which lets you find a control by its ID.

Comment: I actually did try using FindControl but it didnt appear to work properly. I had an error wiggly blue line and I don't think it compiled MikeSmithDev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to iterate through id. then firstly, your html elements should be `runat="server"` and then you can do any of these two:

- you can iterate through the main form controls with a if condition on Id inside
- you can do `.FindControl("ControlId")` in a loop of Controls of the main container i.e form

something like :

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        Dim control As HtmlGenericControl
        control = Me.FindControl("div" + i.ToString())
        If (Not (control Is Nothing)) Then
            'your logic
        End If
    Next
```

but this loop will see only the top level controls, i.e. controls which are directly present in the page. i.e. divs inside another divs won't b found.

you will need a recursive loop for that. see [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199521/vb-net-iterating-through-controls-in-a-container-object). 
it should give you an idea.

am a C# dev, and have no clue of VB. but i guess you got the idea right?

Comment: He's not looking for the JavaScript solution. He is looking for equivalent in VB.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but like mike said I am looking for this type of programming in VB.NET

Comment: Your very last line appears to be what is being asked for.  You should expand it.

Comment: I think this answer must have been edited or else I have just completely not seen that last bit of the post! I will look into that because that looks like it might be what I am after. I will test it.

Comment: @Manish Mishra That is brilliant Manish Mishra... I have taken the basic idea of what you have done there and I have got it to work! I was beginning to think that I would have to apply a completely different approach. Thank you. :) I can't give you a 1 up because my rep is too low unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to read html inside div having ID prefix as  "Div"

You can do that using jquery easily:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
$('Div'+i).html();//this will give you all html within Div0,Div1....Div9
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It is easy enough to do in javascript actually, I already know how to use it in javascript and vbscript. I have to use VB.NET. It is not an option to use Javascript because it is a university project. I may have to find another method to do what I want to do but I need to explore all options.