# How do I close array of webbrowser?

Tags: vb.net

How do I know, how many is open and close them?

```
Dim wb As New WebBrowser
        ChangeUserAgent(TextBox1.Text)
        Me.Controls.Add(wb)
        wb.BringToFront()
        wb.Navigate("https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=" & TextBox3.Text & "&hl=en_US&fs=1&", "_self", Nothing, "User-Agent: " & TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & "Referer:https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=" & TextBox3.Text & vbCrLf)
```

I can open each browser on runtime, however I don't know how to close it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
wb.Dispose()
```

to close the browser control.

Try this link for how to get all of the controls you've added:

[Controls of a Type in Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199521/vb-net-iterating-through-controls-in-a-container-object)

I think this should work for your code:

```
For Each wbControl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf wbControl Is WebBrowser Then            
            wbControl.Dispose()            
    End If
Next
```

Comment: once i press dispost it works , but when i create another webbrowser with the code in post1  then it crashes

Comment: See my edited post.  Get all the controls you've added using the link I posted and then iterate through them and Dispose each one.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199521/vb-net-iterating-through-controls-in-a-container-object

Comment: I edited my post to provide that link instead. There are a ton of resources for getting all the controls of a type on a form.  Sorry, on a phone...

Comment: @azx : It would be better if you said **what the actual problem is** rather than just saying "it crashes", which is _**EXTREMELY**_ vague!

Comment: @azx If this answer helped you, you can accept it and get +2 reputation.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer